# Simplifying Likelihood Ratio

Tags: statistics, summation, statistical-inference

(Answered here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372040/rejection-region-for-likelihood-ratio-test)
I have a data set $((Y_1,x_1),(Y_2,x_2),...,(Y_n,x_n))$ where $Y_i$ is distributed as $N(\theta x_i,1)$. I want to perform a likelihood ratio test for $\theta$ to investigate the hypothesis $H_0: \theta=\theta_0$ or $H_1: \theta\neq\theta_0$:
$$\lambda(X)=\frac{exp(\frac{-\sum_i(Y_i-x_i\theta_0)^2}{2})}{exp(\frac{-\sum_i(Y_i-x_i\hat\theta)^2}{2})}$$ 
Where $\hat\theta$ is the maximum likelihood estimator, which I have determined to be $\frac{\sum_i x_iY_i}{\sum_ix_i^2}$. I want to simplify this ratio as much as possible, but I don't know how to go about this, because $x_i\theta$ varies with $i$, and as such, cannot be taken out of the sum. Normally, I would solve this by adding $0$ (i.e. adding and subtracting a term), but this approach did not help me this time around. Is there a trick that I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the $x_i$'s supposed to be just constants? Or are they random variables?

Comment: They are constants, but each $Y_i$ has a different constant.

Comment: You should probably add in this post that you posted this question later on https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/372040/119261.

Comment: I've done so now. The questions aren't actually the same, though, as I simplified the likelihood ratio in the post on stats.stackexchange. All the same, they're closely related, so I will do as you suggested.

Comment: Cross posting in general is discouraged. In this case I think it was fine as the question did not receive much response here. But if you cross-post, you should mention that you had also asked the question somewhere else, providing the relevant links.